# emulator.exe has stop working?

Tags: android, emulation, offset

I try to run an android example but i keep getting: emulator.exe has stop working.

This is the console lines:

```
[2011-02-11 10:14:49 - Teste] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-02-11 10:14:49 - Teste] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-02-11 10:14:49 - Emulator] 
[2011-02-11 10:14:49 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2011-02-11 10:14:49 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
[2011-02-11 10:14:51 - Emulator] Bad ram offset 74116c00
[2011-02-11 10:14:51 - Emulator] emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
[2011-02-11 10:14:51 - Emulator] 
[2011-02-11 10:14:51 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentred
[2011-02-11 10:14:51 - Emulator] 
[2011-02-11 10:14:51 - Teste] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.android.apis.ApiDemos activity launch'!
```

You know what is this?

Thank you.

Comment: is this on windows7 I also having the same trouble

Answer (score 27):

I too had the Same Problem,

Now i got the solution while searching the internet.

Solution: Edit the Device settings and change the RAM allocation to a lower number. 
If it was 1024 or More, reduce it to 512Mb or 256Mb

You can Change it in "Edit Android Virtual Device (AVD)" dialog's Hardware Section --> Device ram size

Comment: doesn't work for me, it just takes more time to tell me "my app stopped unexpectedly."

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue. So the simplest idea I would suggest:

Try killing the `adb` by just issueing the command `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server` on your command prompt.

Note: If you have not added the `android-sdk-windows\platform-tools` or `android-sdk-windows\tools` directory to the windows path in your system environments then you can not able to run this command directly. Therefore you need to go this path and after that run the above mentioned command.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new AVD and see if the problem persists.

Also, use the -scale parameter to prevent the emulator window from going off screen and being recentered.  You will have to adjust the numbers to find the right size for your display, but start with -scale 0.5 and add increments of 0.1 until it fits.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and restarting ADB wouldn't work for me. Sometimes rebooting my phone worked but not always, I was unable to program for about a week because of this glitch and I think I finally found a workaround! :-D

First of all, kill every program running on your phone. Having some kind of taskmanager makes this a quick task, otherwise you'll have to manually kill them all one at a time.

If that doesn't fix it, you will need to go to your phone settings, then go to "Applications", then go to "Running services", and kill every service in there. I'm using a Droid Incredible and I have yet to have this not work for me. :-)

So, the short answer is, kill all apps, and all services.

Also, keep in mind, you will need to close, and re-open eclipse to see if this fix has worked for you. I hope this works for you, I know it did for me! :-D

Answer (score 0):

I had emulator.exe-arm not working error, and also that i didn't get any error message. After 4 hours of battle and intense searching and testing, i finally found answer.
**UPDATE DRIVERS**
I have intel graphics and AMD, and windows display link messing up my shit. So i downloaded newest drivers everywhere and now everything works.
Things i tried and still remember.
- Resolution tricks
- Ram tricks
- dll copying and moving shit
- Command prompt tricks
- cleaning and installing everything again (x3-5)

Hope this helps someone who is going on same battle and finds this before its too late.