# emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

After starting the android emulator I receive this warning:

```
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

After this warning emulator is displayed without keyboard even I select the both checkbox `"Hardware keyboard present"` and `"Display a skin with hardware controls"`

Comment: In my case, the emulator won't appear at all after displaying that message.  The common move window commands also do not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The android emulator is out of view, how can i move it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572485/the-android-emulator-is-out-of-view-how-can-i-move-it)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572485/the-android-emulator-is-out-of-view-how-can-i-move-it

Answer (score 24):

On **Windows**:

- Check the path `C:\Users\<username>\.android\avd\<avdname>.avd\` and open the file `emulator-user.ini`.

On **Linux**:

- Open the `emulator-user.ini` file located at `/home/<username>/.android/avd/<avdname>.avd/`.

Then set the parameters as

```
window.x = 0
window.y = 0
```

Comment: This works.  My window x value was set to 5963!  That's about a full monitor width to the right of my display area!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The alt-space trick works for me on Win7. First click the emulator (to make the window active). The alt-space. Choose "move". The 4-arrow pointer shows now, but won't work. However, use the keyboard to start moving it around. Once moved by using the keyboard, you can drag it across the screen with your mouse. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HAXM please update it to the latest version and run the HAXM installer again from the sdk directory. If the installer give error, go for a silent run using the bat file. This worked for me. In my case event modifying the user-emulation file was not working.

Answer (score 0):

#### 100% Works

Follow this steps:

1. Go to this directory or press Win+R then type this:
    **(C:\Users\typeyourusername\.android\avd)**
2. Double click the folder (AVD name)
3. Delete the file "**emulator-user**"
4. Run your AVD or (if you already open avd) Close and rerun AVD

Answer (score -1):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7866454/1037442)

Solution: Edit the Device settings and change the RAM allocation to a lower number. If it was 1024 or More, reduce it to 512Mb or 256Mb

You can Change it in "Edit Android Virtual Device (AVD)" dialog's Hardware Section --> Device ram size

Comment: 512mb is the size of ram but reduce the ram size to 256mb but still warning shows.

Comment: This has nothing to do with where the emulator is being launched?