# Have to open emulator 3 times to get the app running every time i open eclipse

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, adb

when I open eclipse and all files are loaded and I run my app, the emulator opens after which I get an error in console.

So Again when I  close the emulator and run the app again, I get the same error in console.

And finally the third time when I run the app, it gets installed and launches the apk. This happens every time I open eclipse.

What is the problem?

Console logs:

```
        [2013-06-01 20:10:58 - CalendarDemo] ------------------------------
   [2013-06-01 20:10:58 - CalendarDemo] Android Launch!
[2013-06-01 20:10:58 - CalendarDemo] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-01 20:10:59 - CalendarDemo] Performing com.indianic.demo.calendark.CalendarActivity activity launch

 [2013-06-01 20:10:59 - CalendarDemo] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD '53' is not available. Launching new emulator.
      [2013-06-01 20:10:59 - CalendarDemo] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device '53'
[2013-06-01 20:11:29 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
 [2013-06-01 20:11:29 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2013-06-01 20:11:30 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
 [2013-06-01 20:11:30 - Emulator] 
  [2013-06-01 20:11:30 - CalendarDemo] New emulator found: emulator-5554
    [2013-06-01 20:11:30 - CalendarDemo] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
  [2013-06-01 20:12:46 - CalendarDemo] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.indianic.demo.calendark.CalendarActivity activity launch'!
     [2013-06-01 20:19:55 - CalendarDemo] ------------------------------
      [2013-06-01 20:19:55 - CalendarDemo] Android Launch!
      [2013-06-01 20:19:55 - CalendarDemo] adb is running normally.
         [2013-06-01 20:19:55 - CalendarDemo] Performing com.indianic.demo.calendark.CalendarActivity activity launch
   [2013-06-01 20:19:55 - CalendarDemo] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD '53' is not available. Launching new emulator.
    [2013-06-01 20:19:55 - CalendarDemo] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device '53'
     [2013-06-01 20:20:20 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
   [2013-06-01 20:20:20 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
  [2013-06-01 20:20:21 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

    [2013-06-01 20:20:21 - Emulator] 
[2013-06-01 20:20:21 - CalendarDemo] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-06-01 20:20:21 - CalendarDemo] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
     [2013-06-01 20:21:14 - CalendarDemo] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
 [2013-06-01 20:21:14 - CalendarDemo] Uploading CalendarDemo.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-01 20:21:16 - CalendarDemo] Installing CalendarDemo.apk...
[2013-06-01 20:22:18 - CalendarDemo] Success!
```

Comment: you might want to [follow this thread][1]

it contain the same error

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652311/emulator-emulator-window-was-out-of-view-and-was-recentered

Comment: @user1549804 comment to the answer  there say changing ram size  does not stop the warnings

Comment: The warning is a known issue - Issue [47829](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=47829). Instead of closing and re-opening the emulator, when eclipse reports emulator disconnection, restarting adb might help to deploy the app on the same emulator.

Comment: @Rajesh how to restart adb.?

Comment: Go to DDMS perspective, click the dropdown in the right most of the "Devices" tab, select "Reset adb"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

First of all, start your desired emulator and then do following steps,

**Step 1:** Right click on your project -> Run As -> Run Configurations

**Step 2:** There will be 3 tabs, `Android | Target | Common` , click on `Target`

**Step 3:** In Deployment Target Selection Mode, select the first option which is `Always prompt to pick device`

**Step 4:** Click on `Apply` and then click on `Run`

As the result, you will get list of currently available devices, you can select desired device and can run the app on it.

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: i want my app to always run on android 4.1.1 so i have selected it from  Run Configurations. no other way out?

Comment: @Metalhead1247: in `Step 3` , you can select `third` option instead of  `first` option

Comment: thank you !! but one of my app is compatible in 2.3 and 4.1.1 but i want it to always open in 4.1.1 any way out there?

Comment: you can change target api.just `right click on that application -> properties -> select desired api level(in your case API 16) as target for compilation -> click ok`

Comment: although follow the steps which I mentioned in previous comment.

Comment: @Metalhead1247: if the suggested steps solves your issue, you can  accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to window->Preferences->Android->DDMS.

change value of adb timeout to 10000.

Since it takes a lot of time for emulator to start, adb times out and the connection is lost
hence the app is not installed.