# why my android emulator won't fully displayed?

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I am run my Android emulator it shows like this picture.

[image: Emulator error]

And it says on the console:

```
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652311/emulator-emulator-window-was-out-of-view-and-was-recentered)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652311/emulator-emulator-window-was-out-of-view-and-was-recentered

Comment: Did you try to change its scale on the AVD Manager? http://developer.android.com/tools/help/avd-manager.html

Comment: I put the scale to auto, but same problem again.

Comment: I don't get that kind of warning.I have got only "emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered"@Stider