# The android emulator is out of view, how to set position center of window?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I know the question is old, and ask many times on stackoverflow but all soltutions not working for me , I am using window 8.1 pro

I have used the following links:

- [The Android emulator is out of view, how can I move it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572485/the-android-emulator-is-out-of-view-how-can-i-move-it)
- [emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652311/emulator-emulator-window-was-out-of-view-and-was-recentered)

I am tried to change the screen Resolution of my screen, also **ALT + SPACE** and **Move** but didn't work as you can see in image no Title bar display,

I have also tried to Edit **C:/Users/UserName/.android/avd/EmulatorName.ini** file with the following code **window.x = 0 window.y = 0** but didn't work

I appreciate your answer if anyone resolve my issue !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue resolved using following procedure

**ALT + Space -> Move**: now move screen by using Arrows (Left, Right, Up, Down) instead of cursor/pointing device

Answer (score 0):

- Click on *emulator*
- press *ALT+Space*
- Press *M*
- Press *Enter*.
  -