# Android Emulator stuck

Tags: android, android-emulator

How to fix this ?

[image]

> C:\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_21 -netspeed full -netdelay
>   none emulator: device fd:504 HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast
>   virt mode emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
>   emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652311/emulator-emulator-window-was-out-of-view-and-was-recentered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this path ***C:\Users\seng\.android\avd*** in this go to your Emulator folder which is **Nexus_5_API_21.avd** edit the file **emulator-user & set the window.x = 0 window.y = 0 or try with assigning your edits.
[Suggestions: *window.x* = 925 *window.y* = 61] .

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

use Genymotion. It is easy to integrate with android studio and is fast as compare to AVD.