# emulator.exe has stopped working in Windows 7 (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I have the following error:
[image]

[I have tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967884/emulator-exe-has-stop-working), but still could not make the emulator work properly.

I have also tried: as per opengl.dll
I have set HOME path JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_SDK_HOME. Still facing the same error
**I have also changed avd configurations** 
ram 512 mg

use host gpu

no skin

api 19 with google api

**My computer:**

i3

64bit

4 gb ram

Comment: - means you have answer right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked GPU Host in AVD Manager?
if you checked Host GPU. Then Uncheck it and again try to Launch AVD.
It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot worked for me too on Windows 7 64 Bit ( i unchecked Host GPU) :)

Answer (score 0):

Start by stopping any adb programs that might be running on the prompt (navigate to where your `adb.exe` is installed, usually:

> C:\Users\ `YOUR USER`\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

Issue `adb kill-server`

Then `adb start-server`

If that does not fix your issue, destroy the AVD, then recreate it.